# Update one list based on another list using stream

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to update items in an existing list from an incoming list.

```
class Person{
  String id;
  String name;
  String age;
.
.
.
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    return ... ((Person) object).id.equals(this.id);
  }
}
```

The current list is shorter:

```
ArrayList<Person> currentList = Arrays.asList(
   new Person("0", "A", 25),
   new Person("1", "B", 35)
);
```

The received list is bigger, e.g.

```
ArrayList<Person> updatedList = Arrays.asList(
       new Person("0", "X", 99),
       new Person("1", "Y", 100),
       new Person("2", "C", 2),
       new Person("3", "D", 3),
       new Person("4", "E", 5)
    );
```

including the items(identified by their **id**) from current list.

I'd like to replace all the items in the current list, with the same one's from new list.

So after transformation, current list will be

```
{ Person(0, "X", 99), Person(1, "Y", 100) }
```

Is it possible to do with Stream only.

Comment: I doubt that you can find a solution that is more elegant than two nested loop. For larger lists, converting one list to a `Map` and doing only one loop has a point, but for such short lists, it won’t pay off.

Comment: Does person class has only three fields? do you want to update only two fields(name and age) from the other list?

Comment: @pvpkiran hi, it may have more fields. Since any field maybe updated, I'd like to replace the objects from the new list directly to the old list.

Comment: There are many details missing. what if some id's are not present in the updatedList? And how big a list are we talking about?

Comment: @pvpkiran it's mentioned new list will include the ids from current. The count maybe in the hundreds at most.

Comment: What do you mean by "operators" and Is there a reason you want to use streams? Using `Collection` methods `removeAll`, `retainAll`, and `addAll`. might be enough and might help readability. For small lists the performance would not be different, I think.

Comment: Right, as other's also mentioned, doesn't look very readable or significantly efficient. Still useful to know the different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the currentList item to be replaced by the object from the updatedList the following should work:

```
currentList.stream().map((p) -> {
            return updatedList.stream().filter(u -> p.equals(u)).findFirst().orElse(p);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `currentList` is always a subset of the `updatedList` - means that all the `currentList` will appear in the `updatedList`, you can do the following:

```
Set<String> setOfId = currentList.stream()
                                 .map(person -> person.getId()) // exctract the IDs only
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());  // to Set, since they are unique

List<Person> newList = updatedList.stream()                     // filter out those who don't match
                                  .filter(person -> setOfId.contains(person.getId()))  
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the `updatedList` and `currentList` differ significantly - both can have unique persons, you have to do the double iteration and use `Stream::map` to replace the `Person`. If not found, replace with self:

```
List<Person> newList = currentList.stream()
    .map(person -> updatedList.stream()                                       // map Person to
                              .filter(i -> i.getId().equals(person.getId()))  // .. the found Id
                              .findFirst().orElse(person))                    // .. or else to self
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                                            // result to List
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using stream,

1. Find list of ids required from currentList
2. filter record having ids in first list

   ```
   List<String> ids = currentList.stream().map(Person::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
   currentList = updatedList.stream().filter(o -> ids.contains(o.getId()))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you are asking.

```
 Map<String, Person> collect = updatedList
                               .stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity()));

 currentList = currentList
               .stream()
               .map(Person::getId)
               .map(collect::get)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @Holger mentioned, doing this for a small List is not so elegant